# Receive No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read when calling web api in browser

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mediatypeformatter

I have an Angular 7 application with a ASP.net web API backend coded in VB.  I can post, put, and get data with no issues, but when I try to access data by a route or id, this is the error I receive:

> The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource.No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'ProjectSummary' from content with media type 'application/octet-stream'.System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

What I am trying to do is call a SQL function where `:id` is a variable that is passed through from the API.  It works fine, in SQL Developer, but not when being accessed by my API.  Here is part of my function:

```
 Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer, <FromBody()> ByVal psum As ProjectSummary)

        Dim reslist As New List(Of Models.ProjectSummary)

        'Dim res As String = String.Empty
        Dim con As New OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BOTDB").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(CommandType.Text, con)
        cmd.CommandText = "select PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_NAME, ROADBLOCKS 
                from TPMT_PROJECT WHERE PROJECT_ID = :id"
```

If I want to get the data for project ID 1, shouldn't I be able to access this data by going to URL .../api/ProjectData/1?

Here is a snippet from my WebApiConfig.vb:

```
  ' Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
    )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have spent considerable time on this one issue.

Comment: This problem depends on how you're formatting the JSON, calling Web API method and HTTP method you're using (GET/POST). Also try setting `Content-Type` to `application/json;charset=UTF-8` if you're sending JSON data.

Comment: Hi Tetsuya.  How do I set the Content-Type?  I have no issues with POST and PUT as my Angular app processes them correctly.  It is only when I add an extra parameter or route to the GET function.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue.  I am a little embarrassed, but the issue was in the declaration of my getValue function haha.

I had 
`Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer, <FromBody()> ByVal psum As ProjectSummary)`

but it should be

```
Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer) As ProjectSummary()
```

Simple oversight.